# why this four parallel threads doesn't load equally on cpu

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I've wrote the following simple code and it should load 4 thread on CPU cores equally. but `htop` results shows that i have one thread with 100% CPU occupation and three threads with 25% CPU occupation. So i doubt that caller thread may have more load on CPU and i got confused. can anybody tell me the reason?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* print_ws( void* unused )
{
    while(1)
        fputc('W',stderr);
    return NULL;
}//print_xs

void* print_zs( void* unused )
{
    while(1)
        fputc('Z',stderr);
    return NULL;
}//print_xs

void* print_xs( void* unused )
{
    while(1)
        fputc('X',stderr);
    return NULL;
}//print_xs

void* print_os( void* unused )
{
    while(1)    
        fputc('O',stderr);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1, t2, t3;
    // create a new thread. the new thread will run the print_xs
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &print_zs, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &print_xs, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t3, NULL, &print_ws, NULL);
    print_os(NULL);
return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: What happens if you replace the `fputc` calls in each of the `print_` routines with just a simple `;` - i.e. if you make each thread routine into a tight, hard-coded, unbreakable loop? That would eliminate any possible lock contention. If you try this you might want to start only three threads for your initial testing. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Works nicely here. Will say I observer an even distrubtion of load for all four threads.

Answer (score 2):

The threads are either waiting for a lock on stderr in libc or they are all competing for the same lock in the operating system. Threads that wait for a lock won't use cpu. I'm surprised though that you have one thread using 100%. They should all be stuck waiting for a lock more or less equally.

Comment: exactly my question is what this is for. I made a test with two threads instead. and result was amazing. CPU load for two threads was as below 

`pid:17984 cpu_load:100`
`pid:17985 cpu_load:50`

so this means that children load is less than parent.
i can't understand the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they might be waiting for a lock to get open so that next threads get executed